# paintEvent not triggered when settting Qt::FramelessWindowHint

Tags: qt, paintevent

I need to play a video using DirectX (d3d) in some QLabel's area, so I have to get the label's `winId` by calling `winid()` method.

But when I do this, the custom button's `paintEvent` does not get called when calling `updata()`, when I call only `winid()` when I set the window flag `FramelessWindowHint` like that:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    HWND hwnd =  (HWND)(ui->label->winId());// here
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);// and here
    QString playBackPre = "_playBack";
    //do my custom button init; the button will draw an pic when press ?enter or leave
    ui->pushButton->setImages(playBackPre, 1);
    ui->pushButton_2->setImages("_quanJin", 1);
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I just had to move the call `winid()` out of the constructor.

Comment: This is by design: a widget being constructed is not visible yet, and thus has no native window identifier. The native window comes into being right after  the widget is shown: the event loop delivers the `QShowEvent` to the widget and you can then query the `winId()`.

Comment: so , if i query the winId(), what happen will it?

Comment: If you query it too early, you'll get an invalid/null value. You can obtain the correct value in reaction to `QEvent::Show` - either by reimplementing `QObject::event` or installing an event filter on the widget.

Comment: thanks. but now, it seems i got an correct value where query the winid in the construction. the only problem is when i call  setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)  i can't triggered the paintEvent in my custom button or label.    but if i query the winid after the construction, the problem not appear

Comment: That's due to implementation details. You probably trigger an unhandled case by calling the `winId` too early. Call it no earlier than the `QEvent::Show` arriving at the window and you should be fine.